# How to configure Envoy as forward proxy to intercept all Egress traffic

Tags: networking, envoyproxy

Is it possible to configure envoy to intercept all egress (i.e., outbound) traffic form a host and redirect them to appropriate upstreams?

My use case is that I'd like to install Envoy on a host and make it responsible for all Egress traffic of all applications on that host without having to modify the application code to forward their traffic to Envoy's listening port.

Is this something Envoy can help with and does anyone have any example of how to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the envoy-dev google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/envoy-dev/nmPwnSid9UA

"Typically this is done with iptables and original_dst routing, you might want to take a look at what Istio does here, this is the canonical example of how to make this work."

Comment: did you find any example of this ? did you make it work with envoy ?

Comment: Not that I remember. This is from four years ago and I no longer have access to the code I was working on then.